# ¿ @oneToMany bidireccional usando @MapsId para usar el mismo id de la tabla padre en tabla hija?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Buenas amigos ojala puedan ayudarme, quiero insertar datos en dos tablas al mismo tiempo usando `@OneToMany` bidireccionalmente reutilizando el ID generado en la tabla padre.

Para eso lei que se ocupa la anotacion `@MapsId` para indicarle a una entidad hija que use el id de la tabla padre, pero desde [postman](/questions/tagged/postman) solo me sirve el metodo get, porque al usar el mismo Json que me retorna con Get para el metodo Post me devuelve este error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type 'Model.Compras' from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

ya le movi a todo usando otras anotaciones como `@EmbeddedId` pero no se que estoy haciendo mal, ojala alguien se anime a ayudarme gracias de antemano.

Estas son mis entidades

Compras:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "compras") 
public class Compras implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer idCompras;
    float total;
    Integer idUsua;
    String fecha;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "compras",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<detallecompras> detalleCompras;   
    
}
```

detalleCompras:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "detallecompras") 
public class detallecompras implements Serializable{

    @Id
    Integer id;
    Integer idProd;
    float precio;
    float cantidad;
    float subTotal;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapsId("idCompras")
    private Compras compras;
}
```